# Accessing Process Messages after Dropped SSH Connection

Tags: ssh

I was doing a `make` operation over ssh, but the connection was dropped, so rather than using `ps -a | grep make`, i was wondering if it was possible for a terminal window to bind what its showing to a specific process (so i can continue to see its rather vebose output)?

Answer (score 1):

Without preparations not as far as I know, when you use the command

```
screen
```

(check man page for details, and or [this info](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/)), you can reconnect to a processes started earlier, very handy thing! Specially in the situation you described.

Comment: Look at `tmux` instead of `screen`, especially if a raspi is involved; it does the same things but is much lighter and has a few advantages.  Alternatively, for a single process, look at `dtach`, which is even lighter.